How do I sort 13 random playing cards in order (sequence) in java?
I want to order 13 playing cards with order clubs, diamonds, hearts and spades, sequence 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,J,Q,K,A.
For example 4C means "4 Club".
I tried using the code below to order them with sample player north like this
4H 5H 8C 8D 9H 9D AC 6S 5D 6D KD 10C AD

the result are
8C AC 10C 5D 6D 8D 9D AD KD 4H 5H 9H 6S

I expected the result
8C 10C AC 5D 6D 8D 9D KD AD 4H 5H 9H 6S

Here is the code

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] sTest = {"4H", "5H", "8C", "8D", "9H", "9D", "AC", "6S", "5D", "6D", "KD", "10C", "AD" };
        
        for (int i=0;i<13;i++) {
            System.out.print(sTest[i]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Sorting");
        ArrayList<String> tmp = sortEnd2Begin(sTest);
        tmp.forEach((String myCard) ->{
            System.out.print(myCard+" ");
        });
        System.out.println();
    }
    
    private static ArrayList<String> sortEnd2Begin(String[] myCards) {
        ArrayList<String> myNewCards = new ArrayList<>();
        myNewCards.add(myCards[0]);
        for (int i=1;i<myCards.length;i++) {
            // loop for unordered myCards
            String card2Sort = myCards[i];
            for (int j=0;j<myNewCards.size();j++) {
                // loop for ordered myNewCards
                // find until card2Sort equal or bigger then existing list
                String cardIterate = myNewCards.get(j);
                int iterMax = card2Sort.length();
                if (card2Sort.length() > cardIterate.length()) {
                    iterMax = cardIterate.length();
                }
                int posCard = beforeOrAfter(card2Sort, cardIterate, 0, iterMax);
                if (posCard==0 || posCard<0) {
                    myNewCards.add(j, card2Sort);
                    break;
                } else {
                    // TODO 
                    //System.out.println(j); // debug
                    if (j+1==myNewCards.size()) {
                        // end of list
                        myNewCards.add(card2Sort);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        return myNewCards;
    }
    
    // -1 wordA before wordB
    // 0 wordA equal wordB
    // 1 wordA after wordB
    private static int beforeOrAfter(String wordA, String wordB, int iterX, int iterMax) {
        //System.out.println(wordA+" "+wordB+" "+iterX+" "+iterMax);
        int inA = wordA.length()-1-iterX;
        int inB = wordB.length()-1-iterX;
        char cA = wordA.charAt(inA);
        char cB = wordB.charAt(inB);
        int retValue = 0;
        if (iterX+1==iterMax) {
            // we reach max recursive {
            //System.out.println(iterX+" "+iterMax+" "+cA+" "+cB); // debug
            if (cA==cB) {
                //System.out.println("Debug"); // debug
                if (wordA.length()<wordB.length())  {
                    retValue = -1;
                } else if (wordA.length()>wordB.length())  {
                    retValue = 1;
                } else {
                    retValue = 0; // equal letters and length
                }
            } else if (cA<cB) {
                //retValue = -1;  // ori
                if (wordA.length()>wordB.length()) {
                    retValue = 1;
                } else {
                    retValue = -1;
                }
            } else if (cA>cB) {
                retValue = 1; // ori
            }
        } else {
            if (cA<cB) {
                //System.out.println(cA+" < "+cB+" "+(cA < cB)); // debug
                retValue = -1; // ori
            } else if (cA>cB) {
                //System.out.println(cA+" > "+cB+" "+(cA > cB)); // debug
                retValue = 1; // ori

            } else {
                //System.out.println(cA+" = "+cB+" "+(cA == cB)); // debug
                retValue = beforeOrAfter(wordA, wordB, iterX+1, iterMax);
            }
        }
        return retValue;
    }
}


Edited 20240708
function sortEnd2Begin uses to sort string array and return ArrayList as a sorted array. function sortEnd2Begin will iterate myCards array, and put it into new arraylist in correct order.
to get correct order in inserting or append arraylist, I use function beforeOrAfter to compare which is lower, equal or higher. if it is lower or equal, it will insert in the begin or middle of arraylist. if end of arraylist reach, it will append the value.
function beforeOrAfter will compare char to char from end of word to determine the word equal, lower or higher order base on ASCII table. function beforeOrAfter will recursive until minimum length of word reached, and determine (return value) -1 (lower), 0 (equal) or 1 (higher).
functions sortEnd2Begin and beforeOrAfter work like sorting file name in file manager, but in reverse order.

It is usually better to use a randomiser to deal cards. You can then choose both suit and face value based on the number returned, from a random value in the range[0..51].

I'm having problems figuring out what you're even trying to do here. Ok, sortEnd2Begin is Arrays.sort. beforeOrAfter is a Comparator. But why do you need to use recursion in there? Wouldn't it be much simpler to first seperate a card into rank and suit and than operate only on these values?

basicallly Arrays.sort(sTest, Comparator.comparing(Cards::suit).thenComparing(Cards::value)), where String suit(String card) returns the suit and Integer value(String card) returns the value of a card (e.g. using the helper Map<String, Integer> values = Map.ofEntries(entry("2", 2), entry("3", 3),..., entry("10", 10), entry("J", 11), entry("Q", 12), entry("K", 13), entry("A", 14)))

despite it would be better (IMO) if we had classes/records to represent the cards, suits, values.

Change your cards from being weakly typed (unsafe and error-prone) to strongly typed and it's trivial to build in ranking as you go. In fact, playing cards, iirc, are a template usage in the Java enum tutorial

That tutorial is here

I added explanation about how functions are work. I use Collections.shuffle(cards, rand) and Random rand = new Random()

You may want to consider using T for 10 as many character based card games do.  It may simplify things.

Suite C, D, H and S are in ASCII order.
The value of suite 2 - 10, J, Q, K and A are not. I remap 10 to A, J to B, Q to C, K to D and A to E to make it ASCII order correctly.
The complete source code to shuffle and distribute cards https://dedetoknotes.blogspot.com/2024/07/java-17-shuffle-52-playing-cards-and.html
the code are
...
            //int posCard = beforeOrAfter(card2Sort, cardIterate, 0, iterMax);
            int posCard = beforeOrAfter2(card2Sort, cardIterate);

...
/* -1 wordA before wordB
 * 0 wordA equal wordB
 * 1 wordA after wordB
 * suite order less C D H S higher
 * value suit  less 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A J K Q
 * map 10 to A
 *      J to B
 *      Q to C
 *      K to D
 *      A to E
 */
private static int beforeOrAfter2(String wordA, String wordB) {
    //System.out.print("word "+wordA+" "+wordB+" "); // debug
    char charA = wordA.charAt(wordA.length()-1);
    char charB = wordB.charAt(wordB.length()-1);
    //System.out.println(wordA+" "+wordB+" End "+charA+" "+charB+" "); // debug
    if (charA<charB) {
        return -1;
    } else if (charA>charB) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        // equal
        charA = wordA.charAt(wordA.length()-2);
        charB = wordB.charAt(wordB.length()-2);
        // mapping charA to correct order
        if (charA=='0') {
            charA='A';
        } else if (charA=='J') {
            charA='B';
        } else if (charA=='Q') {
            charA='C';
        } else if (charA=='K') {
            charA='D';
        } else if (charA=='A') {
            charA='E';
        }
        // mapping charB to correct order
        if (charB=='0') {
            charB='A';
        } else if (charB=='J') {
            charB='B';
        } else if (charB=='Q') {
            charB='C';
        } else if (charB=='K') {
            charB='D';
        } else if (charB=='A') {
            charB='E';
        }
        
        //System.out.println(" First "+charA+" "+charB); // debug
        if (charA<charB) {
            return -1;
        } else if (charA>charB) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}


The operative word is "mapping". So skip the if/else constructs and use one. Map<Character,Integer> map  = Map.of('0', 1, 'J', 2,                   'Q', 3, 'A', 4); return map.get(charA).compareTo(map.get(charB)); Note that you can define the map outside of the method.

Since the last letter represents the suit, you can use it to sort your cards by suits. To sort by values, create a list with the valid order and compare the index of of your strings without the last letter. Use the Comparator interface which makes it easier for you to chain the sorting and makes your code more readable
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> order = List.of("2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A");

        String[] sTest = {"4H", "5H", "8C", "8D", "9H", "9D", "AC", "6S", "5D", "6D", "KD", "10C", "AD" };

        // compare by last char
        Comparator<String> bySuits = Comparator.comparingInt(s -> s.charAt(s.length()-1));

        //compare by the index of substring as they appear in the list
        Comparator<String> byValue = Comparator.comparingInt(s -> order.indexOf(s.substring(0, s.length()-1)));


        System.out.println("Before sorting: " + Arrays.toString(sTest));

        // compare by chaining the two comparators
        Arrays.sort(sTest, bySuits.thenComparing(byValue));

        System.out.println("After sorting: " + Arrays.toString(sTest));
    }
}


There are many ways to do this. Imo, the simplest is to just define a sorted deck of cards in terms of a string and sort on the index of the card as it resides in that string.
String[] sTest = {"4H", "5H", "8C", "8D", "9H", "9D", "AC",
                   "6S", "5D", "6D", "KD", "10C", "AD" };

String sortedDeck = """
     2C3C4C5C6C7C8C9C10CJCQCKCAC\
     2D3D4D5D6D7D8D9D10DJDQDKDAD\
     2H3H4H5H6H7H8H9H10HJHQHKHAH\
     2S3S4S5S6S7S8S9S10SJSQSKSAS\
     """;
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sTest)); // before sorting

Arrays.sort(sTest, Comparator.comparingInt(sortedDeck::indexOf));

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sTest)); // after sorting

prints
[4H, 5H, 8C, 8D, 9H, 9D, AC, 6S, 5D, 6D, KD, 10C, AD]
[8C, 10C, AC, 5D, 6D, 8D, 9D, KD, AD, 4H, 5H, 9H, 6S]


The above presumes some unknown element will not creep into your deck.  Thus, it is presumed that an index of -1 will not be returned during the sort.

Use an enum to define the deck of cards:
public final enum Card
{
  TWO_OF_CLUBS( "2C" ),
  THREE_OF_CLUBS( "3C" ),
  …
  ACE_OF_CLUBS( "AC" ),
  TWO_OF_DIAMONDS( "2D" ),
  …
  TWO_OF_HEARTS( "2H" ),
  …
  ACE_OF_SPADES( "AS" );

  private final String m_Code;

  private Card( final String code )
  {
    m_Code = code;
  }

  public static final Card forCode( final String code ) throws IllegalArgumentException
  {
     final var retValue = stream( values() )
       .filter( v -> v.m_Code.equals( code ) )
       .findFirst()
       .orElseThrow( () -> new IllegalArgumentException( Objects.toString( code ) );
      return retValue();
  }
  
  public final String getCode() { return m_Code; }
  
  @Override
  public final String toString() { return getCode(); }
}

Sorting works now like this:
final String[] sTest = {"4H", "5H", "8C", "8D", "9H", "9D", "AC", "6S", "5D", "6D", "KD", "10C", "AD" };
final var result = stream( sTest )
  .map( Card::forCode )
  .sorted()
  .map( Card::getCode )
  .toArray( String []::new );

The sort order is determined by the sequence you define the enum values in Card.
Funny extension could be add the Unicode code as the symbol to the enum definition:
public final enum Card
{
  TWO_OF_CLUBS( "2C", "\u1F0D2" ),
  THREE_OF_CLUBS( "3C", "\u1F0D2" ),
  …
  ACE_OF_CLUBS( "AC", "\uF0D1" ),
  TWO_OF_DIAMONDS( "2D", "\uF0C2" ),
  …
  TWO_OF_HEARTS( "2H", "\uF0B2" ),
  …
  ACE_OF_SPADES( "AS", "\uF0A1" );

  private final String m_Code;
  private final String m_Symbol;

  private Card( final String code )
  {
    m_Code = code;
    m_Symbol = symbol;
  }

  public static final Card forCode( final String code ) throws IllegalArgumentException
  {
     final var retValue = stream( values() )
       .filter( v -> v.m_Code.equals( code ) )
       .findFirst()
       .orElseThrow( () -> new IllegalArgumentException( Objects.toString( code ) );
      return retValue();
  }
  
  public static final Card forSymbol( final String symbol ) throws IllegalArgumentException
  {
     final var retValue = stream( values() )
       .filter( v -> v.m_Symbol.equals( symbol ) )
       .findFirst()
       .orElseThrow( () -> new IllegalArgumentException( Objects.toString( symbol ) );
      return retValue();
  }
  
  public final String getCode() { return m_Code; }
  public final String getSymbol() { return m_Symbol; }
  
  @Override
  public final String toString() { return getCode(); }
}

This allows to represent the cards like this:
final String[] sTest = {"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "" };
final var result = stream( sTest )
  .map( Card::forSymbol )
  .sorted()
  .map( Card::getSymbol )
  .toArray( String []::new );


Here is the deck and from the deck you get the random hand.
    static String suit[] = {"C", "D", "H", "S"};
    static String sym[] = {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"};
    
    static String card_suit(byte c)
    {
        return suit[c / 13];
    }
    
    static String card_sym(byte c)
    {
        return sym[c % 13];
    }
    
    static void shuffle(byte deck[])
    {
        ArrayList<Byte> list = new ArrayList<Byte>();
        for (int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) list.add(deck[i]);
        Collections.shuffle(list);
        for (int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) deck[i] = list.get(i);
    }
    
    static void print(byte hand[])
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < hand.length; i++)
        {
            byte c = hand[i];
            String card = card_sym(c) + card_suit(c);
            System.out.print(card + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        byte deck[] = new byte[52];
        for (int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) deck[i] = (byte)i;
        
        print(deck);
        shuffle(deck);
        print(deck);
        Arrays.sort(deck);
        print(deck);
    }

